# Model item bind in List

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model

I have passed the model to partial view,And then i need to bind some text fields to the model in the view.

```
@model SRINews.Domain.NewsTotal

@using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateNewsItem", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table table-borderless table-cart" id="mytable" data-addclass-on-smdown="table-sm">
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.items)
            {
                <tr class="newsRow" id="@item.ItemId">
                    <td class="cart-img nostretch">
                        <a href="#"><img src="@item.ImageUrl" alt=""></a>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Personalized Name">
                     //@Html.TextboxFor(x=>x)
                     // I want to bind PersonalizedName to model
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                     <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Country">
                      // I want to bind Country to model
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    }
                    </tbody>
                    </table>

                       <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Personal Details" />

}
```

### Model

```
 public class Items
    {
        public int ItemId { get; set; }
        public string ItemCode { get; set; }
        public string PersonalizedName {get;set;}
        public string Country {get;set;}
    }

    public class NewsTotal
    {
        public int BaseItem { get; set; }
        public string BaseName {get;set;}
        public List<Items> items { get; } = new List<Items>();
    }

Public ActionResult UpdateNewsItem(NewsTotal nTotal)
{
return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a traditional for loop so you can use the index to bind to your `List<T>` in the model, you'll also need to make `items` mutable, so you'll need to have a `set` for it as well or else you won't be able to submit anything:

```
//You'll need to make this mutable, so it can post the edited values
public List<Items> items { get; set; } = new List<Items>();
```

Then in your View:

```
@for(int i = 0; i < Model.items.Count; i++)
{
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.items[i].ItemId)
   @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.items[i].ItemCode)
   <tr class="shoppingCartRow" id="@Model.items[i].ItemId">
     <td class="cart-img nostretch">
       <a href="#"><img src="@Model.items[i].ImageUrl" alt=""></a>
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       @Html.TextboxFor(x=> Model.items[i].PersonalizedName, new { @placeholder = "Personalized Name"})
     </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>
       @Html.TextboxFor(x=> Model.items[i].Country, new { @placeholder = "Country"})
     </td>
   </tr>
}
```

Comment: Now Personalized name & Country is comes to the Model But rest of the thing is NULL

Comment: @TechGuy, that's because only `PersonalizedName` and `Country` are Model bound, you can add other elements to bind the other properties, whether they be hidden or what ever you decide. Just make sure they are contained in the form. I'll update to place the other items properties in the form. Added hidden elements for each items, `id` and `itemcode`

Comment: @TechGuy Ok. Sorry if I over explained it. Glad it helped. Happy coding. :)

Comment: your explanation is very helpful to me . great!